# Hbase Region Server

Tags: hadoop, hbase, cloudera

I'm using Cloudera to set up my hadoop cluster. I've got HBASE up and running, but when I navigate to the hbase web UI, I see that some of the region server URLs are screwy. Seems like the DNS isn't resolving right for some of the hosts. But when I do a nslookup or dig, the results are the same for all the hosts, yet some of them don't display correctly. Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: Make sure your `/etc/hosts` files on all your nodes are right, and then check to see that your DNS is resolving properly.

Answer (score 0):

This was a mistake of mine. I thought reverse DNS was resolving as expected, but it wasn't. D'oh.